# Pyspark Implementation of Oracel Decode

Tags: oracle, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The following oracle SQL command is a one line short command to convert integer to string representation of the value.


 `Select DECODE(employee.active, 1, 'YES', 'NO') from employee`

The same can be achieved in Pyspark using 
 
`employee = employee.withColumn('active', f.when(employee.active == 1, f.lit('YES')).otherwise('NO'))`

is there a pythonic way or Pyspark one-liner that does this ?

Comment: That's Oracle SQL, not PL/SQL. PL/SQL doesn't support `decode`.

Comment: Correction done